# Connected graphs and degree/diameter problem

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem related to the connected graphs:

Show that for every pair of positive integers $(r,s)$, there exist a positive integer $n$ such that for every connected graph $G$ of order $n$, either the maximum degree $\Delta(G)\geq r$ or diam$(G)\geq s$.

I have tried to use the proof of the Moore upper bound on the number of vertices in a general graph when $\Delta(G)\leq r$ and diam$(G)\leq s$ ($n=1+r\frac{(r-1)^s-1}{r-2})$, but I could not get anything related to my problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you know that $$\Delta(G)\le r\text{ and }\operatorname{diam}(G)\le s\implies n\le1+r\frac{(r-1)^s-1}{r-2}$$ then you know that $$n\gt1+r\frac{(r-1)^s-1}{r-2}\implies\Delta(G)\gt r\text{ or }\operatorname{diam}(G)\gt s,$$ right? What else do you want?

Comment: That's absolutely right. I did not think this way! However, I made a mistake in stating the assumption on the Moore Graph. In Moore graphs, it was proved that the number of vertices $n$ of a graph with maximum degree $r$ and diameter $d$ is upper bounded by $1+r\frac{(r-1)^s-1}{r-2}$. Note, here we do not have any inequality on $d$ and $r$. Does the solution you provided still holds?